# Gson Parse Json with array with different object types

Tags: android, json, gson

How can I parse this JSON using Gson? 
I have an array with multiple object types and I don't know what kind of object I need to create to save this structure. I cannot change the json message (I don't control the server).

The only class that function (sort of) was this

```
public class Response {
    private List<Object> tr;
    private int results;

    (...)

}
```

**JSON Message** (Note the array with multiple object types.)

```
{
   "tr":
   [
       {
           "a":
           {
               "userId": "112"
           }
       },
       {
           "b":
           {
               "userId": "123",
               "address":"street dummy" 
           }
       },
       {
           "a":
           {
               "userId": "154"
           }
       }
   ],
"results":3
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Gson User's Guide explicitly covers this:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

You have an object with a field `tr` that is an array containing arbitrary types.

The users guide explains that you can't directly deserialize such a structure, and recomends:

> Use Gson's parser API (low-level streaming parser or the DOM parser
>   JsonParser) to parse the array elements and then  use Gson.fromJson()
>   on each of the array elements. This is the preferred approach.

In your case ... it would really depend on what objects were possible in that array. If they are all going to have that same inner object you'd want to do something like...

```
List<MyUserPojo> list = new ArrayList<MyUserPojo>();
JsonArray array = parser.parse(json).getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("tr");
for (JsonElement je : array)
{
    Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> set = je.getAsObject().entrySet();
    JsonElement je2 = set.iterator().next().getValue();

    MyUserPojo mup = new Gson().fromJson(je2, MyUserPojo.class);
    list.add(mup);
}
```

And of course, this would need to be inside a custom deserializer for your actual object that would have the `tr` and `results` fields.

```
class MyPojo
{
    List<MyUserPojo> userList;
    int results; 
}

class MyUserPojo
{
    String userId;
    String address;
}

class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyPojo>
{
    @Override
    public MyPojo deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
                              throws JsonParseException
    {
        List<MyUserPojo> list = new ArrayList<MyUserPojo>();
        JsonArray array = je.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("tr");
        for (JsonElement je2 : array)
        {
            Set<Map.Entry<String,JsonElement>> set = je2.getAsObject().entrySet();
            JsonElement je3 = set.iterator().next().getValue();                 

            MyUserPojo mup = new Gson().fromJson(je3, MyUserPojo.class);
            list.add(mup);
        }

        MyPojo mp = new MyPojo();
        mp.tr = list;
        mp.results = je.getAsObject().getAsJsonPrimitive("results").getAsInt();

        return mp;
    }
}
```

Now you're all set - you can use that deserializer and create your object:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MyPojo.class, new MyDeserializer())
                .build();

MyPojo mp = gson.fromJson(json, MyPojo.class);
```

If the `a`, `b` etc are important ... well, you'll have to figure that out. But the above should get you well on your way to understanding what's going to be needed to deal with your JSON structure.

For completeness sake, the only "hacky" way around this is if there is a fairly limited number of those types and the inner object also is fairly limited in terms of its fields. You could create a POJO that encompasses all the possibilities:

```
class MyPojo 
{
    MySecondPojo a;
    MySecondPojo b;
    ...
    MySecondPojo f;
}

class MySecondPojo
{
    String userId;
    String address;
    ...
    String someOtherField;
}
```

When Gson deserializes JSON it will set any missing fields in your POJO(s) to `null`. You could now have `tr` be a `List` or array of these in your POJO. Again and to emphasize, **this is really quite hacky and the wrong way to do it**, but I thought I'd explain what would be required to directly parse that array.

Comment: Almost one hour later you build a nice deserializer. Good work but IMHO a bad practice to downvote all other answers just because you can do it better. IMHO a reason for a downvote, but this is too stupid to waste rep for something like that.

Comment: Dude, what are you talking about? I get the email feed of these and answer them at lunch. I just realized it was actually more of  pain than it first looked, but in the end ... yeah, this actually works.

Answer (score 5):

I pick something from each answer and did it this way:

**Response** Object

```
public class Response {
    private List<Users> tr;
    private int results;

    (...)
}
```

Generic **User**

```
public class User {
    public static final int TYPE_USER_A =0;
    public static final int TYPE_USER_B =1;
    private String userId;
    private int type;
    (...)
}
```

**A**

```
public class a extends User {
    private String location;
    (...) 
}
```

**B**

```
public class b extends User { 
    private String adress;   
    (...)
}
```

**Parsing Method**

```
private Response buildResponseObject(String response) {
        Response tls = new Response();
        List<Users> users = new ArrayList<users>();
        User u;

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
            tls.setResults(object.getInt("results"));
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("tr");

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject trs = array.getJSONObject(i);

                if (trs.has("a")) {
                    String json = trns.getString("a");
                    A a = new Gson().fromJson(json,A.class);
                    a.setType(User.TYPE_USER_A);
                    users.add(a);

                } else if (trs.has("b")) {
                    String json = trs.getString("b");
                    B b= new Gson().fromJson(json,B.class);
                    B.setType(User.TYPE_USER_B);
                    users.add(b);
                }
            }

            tls.setUsers(users);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return tls;
    }
```

This is not as elegant as I wanted and mix native JsonObjects with Gson methods but works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code here:

```
public class Address {
    public String userId;
    public String address;
    // ...
}

public class Response {
    private HashMap<String, Address> tr;
    private int results;
    // ...
}
```

Usage:

```
String json = "{\n  \"tr\":\n  {\n    \"a\": {\n       \"userId\": \"112\"\n    },\n    \"b\": {\n       \"userId\": \"123\",\n       \"address\":\"street dummy\"\n    },\n    \"c\": {\n       \"userId\": \"154\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"results\":3\n}";

Response users = new Gson().fromJson(json, Response.class);
```

As you may see I needed to modify the structure:

```
{
  "tr":
  {
    "a": {
       "userId": "112"
    },
    "b": {
       "userId": "123",
       "address":"street dummy"
    },
    "c": {
       "userId": "154"
    }
  },
  "results":3
}
```

But unfortunately I don't get it managed to allow multiple keys. Right now I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: It gives an error on parsing. This may be some kind of mistake from my code but either way, wouldn't the second "a" erase the first object because they have the same key?

Comment: After writing my answer I was asking that myself. I think that class needs to be exchanged by something else. I'll search for an alternative. What is your exception?

Comment: Maybe a `Hashtable` could slove the problem. I'll write a test case for that.

Comment: @Laranjeiro Please review my answer.

Comment: I cannot change the JSON message.

Comment: In this case try Brian Roach's answer, even if he pissed me off by downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might help you:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples

Basically, create a class for your "object" (kind of user I guess), and then use the deserialization code of Gson, like this:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<User>>(){}.getType();
Collection<User> users= gson.fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create corresponding java classes for the json objects. The integer, string values can be mapped as is. Json can be parsed like this-

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Response r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Here is an example- http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/02/url-encode-http-get-solr-request-and.html